# Which file writing methods are available under NTFS "Create Folders / Append Data" permissions?

Tags: c#, .net, file-permissions, ntfs

For example, I am trying to use System.IO.File.AppendText's WriteLine, but that doesn't work, and I believe it's a permissions issue.

Comment: What does "that doesn't work" mean? If you want help, you need to provide specific info. Saying to your mechanic "My car doesn't work. How do I fix it and how much will it cost?" isn't enough, is it?

Comment: If I had logging (aka writing permissions), I could be more specific as to why! :) Tell me, Mr. Anderson, what good is a caught exception if you are unable to log it? Also, in replicating the setup on my machine as close I can, I get a permissions exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that System.IO.File.AppendText opens the file for write access, and simply seeks to its end. Reviewing the code with Reflector should verify that, as will a quick breakpoint on kernel32!CreateFileW with WinDbg.

The program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendText(@"C:\Temp\blah").WriteLine("Boo");
    }
}
```

The breakpoint:

```
KERNEL32!CreateFileW:
757322fb 8bff            mov     edi,edi
0:000> dd esp
002cf1a8  58741b05 022ab244 40000000 00000001
002cf1b8  00000000 00000004 08100000 00000000
002cf1c8  14236e28 59e65d80 002cf270 0000001c
0:000> du 022ab244 
022ab244  "C:\Temp\blah"
```

The dwDesiredAccess parameter is 0x40000000, which is GENERIC_WRITE.

You will most likely have to construct a FileStream yourself:

```
new FileStream("blah", FileMode.Open, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.AppendData, ...)
```